# Incorrect predictions on extracted images from text

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, pytorch, ocr

I trained a model in PyTorch on the EMNIST data set - and got about 85% accuracy on the test set. Now, I have an image of handwritten text from which I have extracted individual letters, but I'm getting very poor accuracy on the images that I have extracted.

One hot mappings that I'm using -

```
letters_EMNIST = {0: '0', 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4', 5: '5', 6: '6', 7: '7', 8: '8', 9: '9',
         10: 'A', 11: 'B', 12: 'C', 13: 'D', 14: 'E', 15: 'F', 16: 'G', 17: 'H', 18: 'I', 19: 'J',
         20: 'K', 21: 'L', 22: 'M', 23: 'N', 24: 'O', 25: 'P', 26: 'Q', 27: 'R', 28: 'S', 29: 'T',
         30: 'U', 31: 'V', 32: 'W', 33: 'X', 34: 'Y', 35: 'Z', 36: 'a', 37: 'b', 38: 'd', 39: 'e',
         40: 'f', 41: 'g', 42: 'h', 43: 'n', 44: 'q', 45: 'r', 46: 't'}
```

For reference, this is an example of the image used for testing data -

[image]

And this is an example of the image I extracted -

[image]

How can I debug this?

Comment: Can you notice the difference between the images you posted? That is the reason... this is not a problem you need to "debug".

Comment: I have updated the image so that they represent the same class. How can I get the second image to look more like the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should check your extraction technique and whether it works correctly. Rest of the answer assumes this step is done.

Distribution of `EMNIST` and distribution of your extracted data is probably quite different, hence it might be hard to obtain good results.

There are some steps you may do to improve the score though.

### Additional data

If you have some way to extract more images of letters and ciphers and label them appropriately you should use it during neural net training.

The more of those you get, the better your results probably be (provided data is of quite high quality, e.g. not many false positives).

### Data augmentation

You could do this without too much work I think.

You have to remember though that **data augmentation has to preserve labels**. So no things like `flipping` (it would be fine for number `8` but `u` flipped could become `n`).

Augmentations which should be fine:

- Small rotations (up to `20` degrees or so)
- Small Gaussian noise or similar
- CutOut with small patches (black rectangulars of size 3x3 pixels or similar being zeroed out on the image)
- Gentle spatial transformations (rescale, shift, linear transformations)
- MixUp (you mix linearly two images with different labels (e.g. image of `A` multiplied by `0.6` and cipher `2` multiplied by `0.4` and try to classify it as `0.6` `A` and `0.4` `2`). Remember labels dont have to be solely binary. This should help your network not to be overconfident with it's predictions

You can find all of those in [`albumentations`](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations) third party library.

### Model augmentation

For your model you could employ thing like dropout (be careful with it's integration with batch norm though), shake shake, Stochastic Depth etc.

### Final

You can use all of those, remember to test how it performs. I tried to list them with the most promising approach on top.

One possibility would be to make the model more robust to variance via augmentation.

Comment: I can't understand why the distribution of data of EMNIST has to be an issue for classifying data. Eventhough the EMNIST set is balanced (near equal occurrences of all classes), once the model is trained and the weights are saved - it should be fine to call the model directly to predict it on a single image to classify it right? I can understand it being an issue if the model itself is trained on an imbalanced set.

Comment: @PyWalker2797 it's not just whether the dataset is balanced or not, there can be all kinds of properties in which EMNIST differs from your crops. For instance, in the example you gave the extracted image is more zoomed in and therefore lacks padding from the edges of the image, which is present in the EMNIST example. I can't generalize having seen only one example, but it's this kind of differences between training dataset and testing dataset which can matter.

Comment: the one about padding makes sense. i'll look into this.

Comment: What I meant is that those two datasets probably are different and the way they were created is different as well. EMNIST was hand chosen, labeled appropriately, maybe rotated, scaled etc. to be quite representative. Your data isn't processed like that. Hence augmentation might move EMNIST distribution closer to your `test` data (same with additional data).

Comment: Thanks, I managed to work on it a little more and get 72% accuracy! Thanks for the tips.